# differntiating between "being paid" and"to be paid"

Tags: infinitives

Would you please show me which on to your ear is more formal?and which one is correct?

There, I worked for a week, without being paid a penny.

There, I worked for a week, without to be paid a penny.

Thanks

Comment: The first is correct: prepositions ordinarily may take gerund clauses as objects but not infinitive clauses.

Answer (score 1):

> There, I worked for a week, without being paid a penny.

This is the correct sentence. 
The other one is simply wrong.

*to be paid* makes sense in a sentence such as *this bill is to be paid by the first of July*.